# typo3: is there a way to see the pages and its html templates in one place?

Tags: typo3

in typo3 admin site, I am using TemplaVoilà to make html templates. I have many pages in my site, so I wonder if there is a way that I can check which page is using which html template in one overall page, instead of checking it one by one, something like:

```
contact page:   home.html
employer page: employer.html
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a hook to add this information in the TemplaVoila s module.